# Colour depth is set too low on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, color-depth

When my computer boots up, the desktop display is alright until the windows desktop icons load. The display resolution then changes to 256 colours and I have to set the colour to true colour 32 bit. This happens each time the computer is restarted. How do I set the colour to remain at true colour 32 bit?

Comment: What is the graphics card in this machine?  Is the correct driver installed?

Comment: Sounds like a program in your startup folder is loading and changing the color depth.  See if any startup programs are running in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have a failsafe setting in MSConfig? I would press <kbd>Winlogo</kbd> +<kbd>R</kbd> and type `msconfig`. Enter the Boot tab, and make sure the `Base Video` box is **not** checked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to calibrate your display and seeing if that holds? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Calibrate-your-display

Answer (score 0):

In control panel you might have configuration settings specific to your video card. For example my NVIDIA card installed a "NVIDIA Control Panel" button in my control panel. You might have one for ATI or Intel GMA depending on the chip on your video card.

Try changing the color depth in the video card specific graphics settings instead of using the settings provided by windows.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the graphics card driver is installed first in All Programs. If not, download the drivers from either AMD or nVidia, depending on which graphics card you have.

Often, the display does not work correctly because the driver is not installed or out of date.

Answer (score -1):

***Left Click Mouse*** and ***Screen Resolution*** and advanced Setting to ***List Modes***
and Select our Size Monitor.